Elasticsearch C# filter bool fields which are set to true
I use Elasticsearch C# client Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.13.3. I would like to filter records where 'some_field' is set to true. So only records with 'some_field' = false should be returned. And I'm not interesting in score. I came to the following two queries:
var qry1 = new TermQuery(some_field)
 {
     Value = false
 };

And:
var qry2 = new BoolQuery()
 {
     MustNot = new List<Query>
     {
         new TermQuery(some_field)
         {
             Value = true
         }
     }
 }; 

Are these queries identical? If not what's the difference and which one should I prefer?
